# Why gmake fails if vpath points to current directory

Tags: gnu-make

Why this doesn't work? If I remove VPATH or set it to '.' - all fine.
Empty `dir`, `a.cpp`, `b.cpp` exist before running.

```
VPATH=./.
dir/lib.a: dir/a.o dir/b.o
        touch $@

x:
        touch x

dir/%.o: %.cpp | x
        touch $@
```

Comment: Have you tried to `diff` the output of `make -np` versus `make -npf /dev/null` to find out where it differs functionally? Also, why the abundance of trailing whitespace?

Comment: Removed trailing whitespace. Tried  -np - can't find anything useful. Non-vpath version says 'pruning file x'. Vpath version says 'Ignoring VPATH name ././dir/b.o' and result in 'no rule to make 'dir/b.o' needed by 'dir/lib.a'.
Funny but if VPATH is '.' there is special hack in code so VPATH=='.' is like no VPATH.

Comment: Remeber the  `\t` before the actions (`\t touch ...`). `./.`looks strange to me!

Comment: Create 1 file with what you deem functional and one as reproduced above. Then call `diff -u <(make -npf makefile1) <(make -npf makefile2)` ...

Comment: That's not that easy in this case as you also need to clean.

Comment: \t is there - dir/a.o is built ok. Yes ./. look strange, but this is because VPATH is kind of auto generated in script it may be that or something else. I understand to use VPATH is quite stupid idea, but i want to understand why make doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @gena2x: yeah, your question is also not an easy case as you ask why something doesn't work and expect us to infer what your actual problem is. It would make more sense if you gave us the root problem, then what you tried (we have that) and then perhaps what you expect to see. Your question is like "why does that hammer not work for fastening this screw?" when your question should be "how can I fasten that screw?" ;) You don't even give the working and non-working version, because puzzle pieces are missing to reproduce this on any given machine. You don't give those.

Comment: I made question more explicit. I tried hard to remove all unnecessary information from question.

Comment: You are *completely* missing the point. I tried on my system the following: `diff <(make -npf makefile1) <(make -npf makefile2)|grep -E '^[+-]#'` ... only difference `VPATH=.` versus `VPATH=./.` ... now guess what? They are identical. In short: your question lacks enough information to even attempt to answer it.

Comment: I produce separate logs for each case with `make -dp` and did `diff -u ok.log fail2.log |wc -l`, it says there is 730 lines of difference.

Comment: Ah, sorry missed '-n' in your suggestion! Let me try...

Comment: The edit helped. I can now not only reproduce the problem but also see the issue.

Comment: Eh, probably that is too narrow for stackexchange anyway...

Comment: Tried -n - everything looks fine. Rule for dir/b.o looks the same in both versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but comments are not suitable to show the differences. And that's the vital information you need.

makefile1:

```
VPATH=./.
dir/lib.a: dir/a.o dir/b.o
        touch $@

x:
        touch $@

dir/%.o: %.cpp | x
        touch $@
```

makefile2:

```
VPATH=.

dir/lib.a: dir/a.o dir/b.o
        touch $@

x:
        touch $@

dir/%.o: %.cpp | x
        touch $@
```

**Attention** the prefix character for the recipes is a tab. Mind that if you copy&paste the content.

The folder `./dir` is empty and the two files `./a.cpp` and `./b.cpp` exist inside the folder with the make file(s).

Invoking `make -f makefile1` gives an error as follows:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `dir/b.o', needed by `dir/lib.a'.  Stop.
```

Invoking it on `makefile2` gives the expected result and reports no errors.

When printing the database while running make, the differences are as follows between `makefile1.log` and `makefile2.log`:

```
--- /dev/fd/63  2015-04-13 18:31:30.370203634 +0000
+++ /dev/fd/62  2015-04-13 18:31:30.370203634 +0000
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
 touch x
 touch dir/a.o
+touch dir/b.o
+touch dir/lib.a
 <D = $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $<))
 ?F = $(notdir $?)
 CWEAVE = cweave
@@ -99,7 +101,7 @@
 SSH_CLIENT = ...
 MAIL = /var/mail/user
 LEX.l = $(LEX) $(LFLAGS) -t
-VPATH = ./.
+VPATH = .
 +D = $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $+))
 COMPILE.r = $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(RFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
 TMUX = /tmp/tmux-1000/default,3455,0
@@ -282,6 +284,8 @@
    $(GET) $(GFLAGS) $(SCCS_OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
 %:: SCCS/s.%
    $(GET) $(GFLAGS) $(SCCS_OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
+dir/lib.a: dir/a.o dir/b.o
+   touch $@
 .web.p:
    $(TANGLE) $<
 .l.r:
@@ -297,6 +301,8 @@
    $(RM) y.tab.c
 .o:
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
+x:
+   touch $@
 .y:
 .def.sym:
    $(COMPILE.def) -o $@ $<
@@ -331,8 +337,6 @@
    $(COMPILE.r) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
 .r:
    $(LINK.r) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
-dir/a.o: a.cpp | x
-   touch $@
 .info:
 .elc:
 .l.c:
@@ -344,7 +348,6 @@
    $(LINK.C) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
 .r.f:
    $(PREPROCESS.r) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
-dir/b.o:
 .S:
    $(LINK.S) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
 .texinfo.info:
@@ -359,6 +362,7 @@
    $(COMPILE.s) -o $@ $<
 .s:
    $(LINK.s) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
+b.cpp:
 .texinfo.dvi:
    $(TEXI2DVI) $(TEXI2DVI_FLAGS) $<
 .el:
@@ -372,6 +376,8 @@
    $(MAKEINFO) $(MAKEINFO_FLAGS) $< -o $@
 .DEFAULT:
 .h:
+dir/a.o: a.cpp | x
+   touch $@
 .tex.dvi:
    $(TEX) $<
 .cpp.o:
@@ -384,10 +390,10 @@
 .texi:
 .txinfo:
 .tex:
+dir/b.o: b.cpp | x
+   touch $@
 .txinfo.info:
    $(MAKEINFO) $(MAKEINFO_FLAGS) $< -o $@
-dir/lib.a: dir/a.o dir/b.o
-   touch $@
 .ch:
 .S.s:
    $(PREPROCESS.S) $< > $@
@@ -398,8 +404,6 @@
 .F.f:
    $(PREPROCESS.F) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
 .w:
-x:
-   touch $@
 .S.o:
    $(COMPILE.S) -o $@ $<
 .F:
```

These were retrieved with the following command:

```
$ /usr/bin/diff <(grep -vE '(^#|makefile1|^\s*$)' makefile1.log) <(grep -vE '(^#|makefile2|^\s*$)' makefile2.log)
```

## The differences

The real difference appears to be that makefile2 has a phony target for `b.cpp` and that it contains the following:

```
touch dir/b.o
touch dir/lib.a
```

also the rule for `dir/b.o` differs considerably between the two.